# uname mac linux

Tags: linux, macos

Estoy  en el terminal de Mac me piden ingresar uname para conocer el sistema operativo me dice linux cuando oprimo enter , pero me piden ingresar la salida de comando , no se cual es

Comment: Bienvenida a SO. Creo que va a ser mas efectivo que coloques (en la pregunta original) lo que te aparece en el terminal, como texto, por favor. No te preocupes si no lo sabes editar para que quede con formato diferente. Eso lo podemos corregir los editores una vez que lo tengas puesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Entonces ejecuta el comando `uname` y verifica que es lo que dice.